# Получение данных из фрагмента в активити без FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragment

В приложении рейсайклер находится в фрагменте. Необходимо получить индекс нажатого элемента, чтобы вывести определенную информацию.

Написал Callback, он передает из адаптера в фрагмент индекс. Но столкнулся с глупой задачей, к которой не особо представляю как подступиться.

Дело в том, что этот фрагмент находится в табах, и добавляется он следующим образом:

```
 String tabs[] = {
            "FORM",
            "PREVIEW"

    };

    public SuggestTabsPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return SuggestTermFragment.getInstance();
            case 1:
                return SuggestTermFragment.getInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}
```

Иначе говоря, `FragmentManager` не используется, и я не особо представляю, каким образом мне из фрагмента получить нужный индекс для активити.

Пробовал сделать метод(не статический), который получает инту. Но через `getActivity()` этот метод был не виден(явно приводил к MainActivity - не помогло).

Впринципе, можно сделать и статиком, но это слишком. Может есть какой-то более гуманный выход?

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведение к MainActivity должно работать. Покажите как оно у вас не работало

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил ответ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `public int setSheetIndex(int sheetIndex){
        return sheetIndex;
    }`   метод в активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно синтаксически кастуете результат вызова метода к классу. Вам надо так, окружив скобками результат:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).METHOD_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS();
```

Или так - создав переменную нужного типа:

```
MainActivity activityMain = (MainActivity) getActivity();
activityMain.METHOD_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY_CLASS();
```

Comment: Ну рукалицо прост =_=